# Eigen vectors and determinant of a block matrix

Tags: matrices

I have two questions regarding matrix $A$. The matrix $A$ can be partitioned into four tridiagonal matrices $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$. 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} A_1&A_2\\A_3&A_4 \end{pmatrix}$$; Ai is a 9 by 9 tridiagonal matrix with 2 unknown parameters in it. 
How can I get the eigen values of $A$ in terms of unknown.

If I know the eigen values exactly for matrix $A$. I want to find the values of eight parameters inside $A$ so that the eigen values stay the same.

Comment: I do not understand your last two sentences. Which eight parameters?

Comment: You could also give more information regarding the dimensions of the block matrices. And your question is not understable to me right now.

Comment: There are eight unknown elements in the matrix A. By initially varying the value of each of them,we can get a new version of matrix A and associated eigen values. Hope it is clear now. The dimension of the matrix is 18 by 18